# Count specific value in table in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm newbie and having a trouble on how can I count the number of `value 1` and `value 2` under the header 2 based on the image I attached. So the result of `value 1` should be `2` and the `value 2` should also `2` Is there any trick how can I solve this, Im new with this,I hope anyone can help.

[image]

*This is what I tried my html*

```js
var tds = document.getElementById('table').getElementsByTagName('td');
var sum_paid= 0;
var x = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < tds.length; i ++) {
    if(tds[i].className == 'count_value"' && tds[i].innerHTML =="Value 2" ) {
      i++;
      }
     else if (tds[i].className == 'count_value"' && tds[i].innerHTML =="Value 1" ) {
        i++;
     }
}
console.log(x);
console.log(i);
```

```html
<table id="table" name="table" id="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 2</th>
        <th>Header 3</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Value 1</td>
            <td class="count_value">Value 1</td>
            <td>Value 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Value 1</td>
            <td class="count_value">Value 2</td>
            <td>Value 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Value 2</td>
            <td class="count_value">Value 1</td>
            <td>Value 1</td>
        </tr>   
        <tr>
            <td>Value 2</td>
            <td class="count_value">Value 2</td>
            <td>Value 1</td>
        </tr>       
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Tables represent data. That data collection has your answer. Parsing the HTML should be the last resort. The next bit of data to extract from the table will require a different set of HTML parsing gymnastics. Where is the table created and where does the data come from? If this is simply a contrived example, the start by defining the data in JavaScript and you have your answer. The HTML is simply there to display that data to the end user - you can build that with JavaScript easily. Focus on data - not on what you see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an option - just grab all elements with the class you have set on the second-column elements (`"count_value"`), and check if the text in those elements (`elem.innerText`) contains a `"1"` or `"2"`.

```js
let elementsToCount = document.querySelectorAll('.count_value');

let numOne = 0, numTwo = 0;

elementsToCount.forEach((elem) => {
    if (elem.innerText.includes('1')) numOne++;
    if (elem.innerText.includes('2')) numTwo++;
})

console.log("Number one:", numOne);
console.log("Number two:", numTwo);
```

```html
<table id="table" name="table" id="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 2</th>
        <th>Header 3</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Value 1</td>
            <td class="count_value">Value 1</td>
            <td>Value 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Value 1</td>
            <td class="count_value">Value 2</td>
            <td>Value 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Value 2</td>
            <td class="count_value">Value 1</td>
            <td>Value 1</td>
        </tr>   
        <tr>
            <td>Value 2</td>
            <td class="count_value">Value 2</td>
            <td>Value 1</td>
        </tr>       
    </tbody>
</table>
```